# How do I add Text label in CGRect?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have made a path, and to center it I have used `CGRect`. I want to add some text to the path at an exact position. However, since I have centered the path using `CGAffineTransform` I can't just write in the coordinates with the `.position` function.

This is my path:

```
struct elevationLegend: Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
        
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 10, y: (100 - (90-0))))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 10, y: (100 - (90-180))))
        
        let scale = (rect.width / 350) * (9/10)
        var xOffset = (rect.midX / 4)
        var yOffset = (rect.midY / 2)
        
        return path.applying(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale, y: scale)).applying(CGAffineTransform(translationX: xOffset, y: yOffset))
        
    }
}
```

And this is my hopeless try of trying to position the Text.

```
struct eText: TextField {
    
    func text(in rect: CGRect) -> String {
        
        let swag = Text("90").position(x: 10, y: 100 - (90-180))
        
        let scale = (rect.width / 350) * (9/10)
        var xOffset = (rect.midX / 4)
        var yOffset = (rect.midY / 2)
        
        return swag.applying(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale, y: scale)).applying(CGAffineTransform(translationX: xOffset, y: yOffset))
    }
}
```

This dosen't work. Does anyone have an idea on how I can fix this problem

Comment: SwiftUI goes different way... would you describe what do you try to achieve?

Comment: @Asperi I want to create a graph (with paths), and then add some labels to the x and y axis